# Python wordcloud can't present Hebrew

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, data-visualization, word-cloud

I am trying to create wordcloud to a text in Hebrew.
The text is:

> את הסיפור שלנו סיפרנו לעצמנו כל הזמן. בכפייתיות. בעל פה. לפעמים
>   התעייפנו עוד לפני שהתחלנו ובכל זאת סיפרנו במשך שעות. הקשבנו רוב קשב
>   אחד לשני, כי בכל ערב שבו סופר הסיפור, התחוורו לנו פרטים חדשים, גם שנים
>   רבות אחרי שכבר לא היינו שם. למשל, לא ידענו שחלק מילדי קבוצת "אורן"
>   שהיו מבוגרים מאיתנו בחמש שנים עבדו עם הבוקרים. ושהם חיו במובלעת של חיי
>   כפר הונגרי בתוך הקיבוץ שלנו. לא ידענו שלוֹפֶס ("זין של סוס") שימש
>   כברְכת בוקר טוב וערב טוב. לא ידענו שאיתי מ"אורן" רכב על סוסה ברחבי
>   הגבעות שלנו באין מפריע כבר כשהיה בן שש. הסיפורים סופרו רק בעל פה,
>   בניגוד לכל התקנונים הכתובים. הם בקעו מבורות הממטרות בדשאים שהקיפו את
>   חדר האוכל, מחרכי המבצר הצלבני שלנו, מהחריצים במדרכות האבן הצרות
>   והיפות. את סיפורינו היינו מספרים בעיניים בורקות. אמרנו, "לא ייאמן שאת
>   הפרות היו שוחטים על הרמפה, לעינינו, את ראשי התרנגולות היו מולקים,
>   כאילו כלום," אבל דיברנו כאילו היו אלה שנותינו היפות. ואלה באמת היו
>   שנותינו היפות, טבולות בזהב. דווקא כי חיינו בטמפרטורה של מתחת לאפס בחום
>   הלוהט של שמש נצחית. היינו דרוכים ומסוקרנים בכל יום מחדש. היינו ערים
>   בבקרים וערים בלילות. רצנו ודילגנו ממקום למקום, ידינו דביקות משרף
>   אורנים וחלב תאנים. כל כך קרובים היינו אחד לשני, כל היום וכל הלילה,
>   ובכל זאת לא ידענו כלום אחד על השני. ולא ידענו כלום על עצמנו. תמיד
>   סיפרנו, עוד אז, בלילות ירח כתום, בבית הילדים. כבר אז סיפרנו יומם
>   ולילה, כדי לישון, כדי לא לישון, יושבים במסדרון בפתחי החדרים, או על
>   המיטות בתוך החדרים, ומגזימים למוות את חופשותינו העירוניות עם המשפחות
>   הביולוגיות שלנו (נסענו, אמא ואבא ואחים. במשך שבוע היינו משפחה עירונית,
>   לבושים בבגדי נסיעה חגיגיים שעברו בין כל הילדים הנוסעים לעיר). כשחזרנו,
>   כל אחד לחוד מדירת הקיבוץ ברחוב שינקין בתל אביב, סיפרנו על אותו קרקס
>   מדראנו שכולם הלכו אליו. אלא שאותו ערב שבו היינו עם משפחתנו הביולוגית
>   בקרקס לא דמה לערבים האחרים - באותו ערב אריות ברחו מהכלוב, לוליין נפל
>   מהחבל, ככה אמרנו. סיפרנו אחד לשני סיפורים שבינם לבין המציאות לא היה
>   דבר. לפעמים, אחרי שעזבנו, ניסינו לספר את סיפורנו לעירוניים. לא הצלחנו
>   להעביר את הסיפור, לא את העלילה ולא את הטון. קולנו צרם, כ

And I use the following code (The text is given in a seperate .txt file):

```
import codecs
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)
book_txt_f = codecs.open(fn, "r", encoding="UTF-8")
book_txt = book_txt_f.read(2000)

wordcloud = WordCloud(
        background_color='white', stopwords=stopwords,  max_words=200, max_font_size=40, scale=3, random_state=1).generate(str(book_txt))

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(6, 6))
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.show()
```

But the figure (attached) can't present Hebrew:
[image]
What might be the reason? How can I fix it?

Comment: It looks like the encoding of your incoming file is not the same as when you read it in (i.e. `book_txt.decode("utf-8")` ? - maybe the text file is Unicode encoded?

Comment: @ochi utf-8 should handle Unicode, isn't it? How can I check if the file is unicode encoded? I am using windows

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the file? Could be it's encoded differently such as `utf-16` but it should be in `utf-8`.

Comment: fixed using this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063438/create-wordcloud-in-python-for-foreign-language-hebrew

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create wordcloud in python for foreign language (Hebrew)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063438/create-wordcloud-in-python-for-foreign-language-hebrew)

Answer (score 1):

This is not actually an issue with the encoding of the text file (you can check this with `print(book_txt)`), but with the font used by WordCloud. You can specify a `font_path` when creating the WordCloud object. For example, using the Courier Bold font on Windows:

```
wordcloud = WordCloud(
        font_path = 'C:\Windows\Fonts\courbd.ttf',
        background_color='white',
        stopwords=stopwords, 
        max_words=200,
        max_font_size=40,
        scale=3,
        random_state=1).generate(book_txt)
```

Output:

[image: Hebrew word cloud]