# How to generate wordcloud of bangla text in python?

Tags: python, nlp, data-visualization, word-cloud, bangla-font

I tried the code below :

```
!pip install python-bidi
from wordcloud import WordCloud
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

text="""মুস্তাফিজ"""

bidi_text = get_display(text)
print(bidi_text)
# https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/issues/367
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063438/create-wordcloud-in-python-for-foreign-language-hebrew
# https://www.omicronlab.com/bangla-fonts.html
rgx = r"[\u0980-\u09FF]+"
wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path='/content/Siyamrupali.ttf').generate(bidi_text)

#wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path='/content/FreeSansBold.ttf').generate(bidi_text)
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

then i get this error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-56d899c0de07> in <module>()
     12 # https://www.omicronlab.com/bangla-fonts.html
     13 rgx = r"[\u0980-\u09FF]+"
---> 14 wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path='/content/Siyamrupali.ttf').generate(bidi_text)
     15 
     16 #wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path='/content/FreeSansBold.ttf').generate(bidi_text)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/wordcloud/wordcloud.py in generate_from_frequencies(self, frequencies, max_font_size)
    381         if len(frequencies) <= 0:
    382             raise ValueError("We need at least 1 word to plot a word cloud, "
--> 383                              "got %d." % len(frequencies))
    384         frequencies = frequencies[:self.max_words]
    385
```

**ValueError: We need at least 1 word to plot a word cloud, got 0.**

this line is not picking bangla words : wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path='/content/Siyamrupali.ttf').generate(bidi_text)

i tried almost all the fonts from here for bangla language : https://www.omicronlab.com/bangla-fonts.html

nothing works

Answer (score 2):

You didn't change **regexp** with your defined one in the word cloud. While processing the text in the word cloud, it couldn't match the pattern and returned an empty list.
Passing **rgx** variable while creating a word cloud object will solve your issue.

```
wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path='/content/Siyamrupali.ttf',regexp=rgx).generate(bidi_text)
```

Here is the full snippet of the code.

```
!pip install python-bidi
from wordcloud import WordCloud
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

text="""মুস্তাফিজ"""

bidi_text = get_display(text)
print(bidi_text)
# https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/issues/367
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54063438/create-wordcloud-in-python-for-foreign-language-hebrew
# https://www.omicronlab.com/bangla-fonts.html
rgx = r"[\u0980-\u09FF]+"
wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path='/content/Siyamrupali.ttf', 
regexp=rgx).generate(bidi_text)

#wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path='/content/FreeSansBold.ttf').generate(bidi_text)
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have generated a word cloud in Bangla using the following code. You can try it out:

def generate_Word_cloud(self,author_post, vocabularyWordnumber, img_file, stop_word_root_path):

```
stop_word_file = stop_word_root_path+'/stopwords-bn.txt'
print(stop_word_file)
f = open(stop_word_file, "r", encoding="utf8")
stop_word = f.read().split("\n")
print(stop_word)

final_text = " ".join(author_post)
print(final_text)
wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords = stop_word, font_path='/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/kalpurush.ttf',
    width = 600, height = 500,max_font_size=300, max_words=vocabularyWordnumber,
                      min_word_length=4, background_color="black").generate(final_text)
wordcloud.to_file(img_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this comment](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3593#issuecomment-455725034) and could solve the problem in Ubuntu eventually.

**Step 1**:

```
!sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev libharfbuzz-dev libfribidi-dev gtk-doc-tools
```

**Step 2**:

```
!wget -O raqm-0.7.0.tar.gz https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-pillow/pillow-depends/master/raqm-0.7.0.tar.gz
```

*Now the raqm-0.7.0.tar.gz file should be in your downloads section.*

**Step 3**:

```
!tar -xzvf raqm-0.7.0.tar.gz
```

**Step 4**:

```
!cd raqm-0.7.0
```

**Step 5**:

```
!./configure --prefix=/usr && make -j4 && sudo make -j4 install
```

**Step 6**:

Now you just have to reinstall the Pillow library. Activate the correct environment. Then run the following commands:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

That's it! Now you have a working Pillow library that can produce proper Bengali and other Indic fonts in the image.

Also, as suggested by @Farzana Eva in her comment, you need to pass the rgx variable in the wordcloud object.